# date time in combobox

Tags: sql, sql-server, vb.net

i am using visual stdio 2008 and sql server 2005

```
dim selectquery = "SELECT Purchase_master.Customer_name, Purchase_details.Item_code, Item_Master.Name,
    Purchase_details.Quantity, Purchase_details.Cost, Purchase_master.Date 
    FROM Item_Master INNER JOIN (Purchase_master INNER JOIN Purchase_details ON
    Purchase_master.Bill_id = Purchase_details.Bill_id) ON Item_Master.Item_code = Purchase_details.Item_code
    WHERE Purchase_master.Date= " + cboPDate.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

when this selectquery executed it gives me 
error

"ERROR near syntax 12"

my cboPDate is a combobox binded with my database which return's data and time in
"2/18/2011 12:00:00 AM"

please help me out

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I suspect it is treating it as a delimiter.It would be better to change it to

```
WHERE Purchase_master.Date=@Your_date
```

And then add the date as a parameter, this would prevent SQL injection attacks and also promote plan caching

Answer (score 2):

You need to add quotes around your date.

Try

```
dim selectquery = "SELECT Purchase_master.Customer_name, Purchase_details.Item_code, Item_Master.Name,
    Purchase_details.Quantity, Purchase_details.Cost, Purchase_master.Date 
    FROM Item_Master INNER JOIN (Purchase_master INNER JOIN Purchase_details ON
    Purchase_master.Bill_id = Purchase_details.Bill_id) ON Item_Master.Item_code = Purchase_details.Item_code
    WHERE Purchase_master.Date= '" + cboPDate.SelectedValue.ToString() +"'"
```

Better yet, use [SQL parameters](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/yy6y35y8.aspx).

Comment: now it is show this error"Incorrect syntax near '2/18/2011 12:00:00 AM'."

Comment: That sounds very strange. If you debug and copy the value from selectquery what do you get? Are you appending anything else to selectquery before executing it?

Comment: this is wht i am getting in selectquery is                   "SELECT Purchase_master.Customer_name, Purchase_details.Item_code, Item_Master.Name,Purchase_details.Quantity, Purchase_details.Cost, Purchase_master.Date FROM Item_Master INNER JOIN (Purchase_master INNER JOIN Purchase_details ON Purchase_master.Bill_id = Purchase_details.Bill_id) ON Item_Master.Item_code = Purchase_details.Item_code WHERE (((Purchase_master.Date)= '2/18/2011 12:00:00 AM'"

Comment: You have a couple open brackets before Purchase_master.Date that aren't closed.

Comment: srry it is my fault bro i didn't saw the round brackets near where clause  i got it  but thanks for ur help

Comment: No worries. I really would recomment you using SQl parameters though. It has built in prevention of SQL injection.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
dim selectquery = string.Format("SELECT Purchase_master.Customer_name,     Purchase_details.Item_code, Item_Master.Name,
Purchase_details.Quantity, Purchase_details.Cost, Purchase_master.Date 
FROM Item_Master INNER JOIN (Purchase_master INNER JOIN Purchase_details ON
Purchase_master.Bill_id = Purchase_details.Bill_id) ON Item_Master.Item_code = Purchase_details.Item_code
WHERE Purchase_master.Date= '{0}'", cboPDate.SelectedValue.ToString());
```

you have to add quots to the value. :)

Comment: now it is show this error"Incorrect syntax near '2/18/2011 12:00:00 AM'."